# Finding the number of days and time between 2 dates/times in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-formula

As an example I have 2 columns, A and B - both respectively titled Date and Time.

In A2 I have: 
4/03/2012

In A3 I have: 
8/03/2012

In B2 I have: 
20:34:09

And finally in B3 I have: 
17:35:40

So basically I'd like to find out the time between "4/03/2012 20:34:09" and "8/03/2012
 17:35:40".

Currently I have: =(A3+B3)-(A2+B2) in the cell A5.

This works as it shows "3/01/1900 21:01" which is the day and time difference between the two.

Also in cell A6 I have a formula which represents this in a nice format: 
=TEXT(A5, "dd    hh:mm:ss"). So the above result looks like "03    21:01:31".

However the problem occurs when A3 is changed to "4/03/2012". 
Since now A6 shows "#VALUE!" when it should show: 00    02:58:29
. Also A5 shows #####.....etc

I am not quite sure on how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't have the best reasoning behind why this is happening, but one solution would be to combine the date and time in an intermediate cell, then calculate the difference off those two intermediate cells.

So for example, in C2 put `=A2+B2` and in C3 put `=A3+B3` and then in A5 put `=C3-C2`. Now the unformatted value will actually calculate correctly. Finally, change your text formatting to be something like this:

`=TEXT(ABS(A5), IF(A5<0,"-","") & "dd hh:mm:ss")`

This will display the time difference formatted like before but with the negative sign if needed.

(Would love to hear if someone can explain the details as to why this is happening.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're getting an error due to negative times. Also the `dd` format will only allow for up to 31 days between dates, as it is representing the date relative to January 1900. You can try:

```
A5:  =ABS(A3+B3-A2-B2)
A6:  =TEXT(INT(A5),"00")&TEXT(MOD(A5,1)," hh:mm:ss")
```

If you want to keep the sign you can prepend `SIGN(A3+B3-A2-B2)` to the formula

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP010070468.aspx)!.

I think this may help you (partial limk information attached)

[image]

Comment: I already looked through the pages. Nothing that will assist me there on the issue. The issue occurs when the end time is less than the start time as excel gives an error if for instance you're trying to find out what is 5:00pm - 10:00pm. It should result in 5hrs but that does not happen. You did not read my question fully.

Comment: hi dude, try this a3+b3 and a2+b2 values are stored in d2 and d3 respectively then in a5 = max(d2,d3)-min(d2,d3) and do your =TEXT(A5, "dd hh:mm:ss")